# Selenium protect ports

Tags: c#, selenium

I can't solve this problem for more than a week. I tried everything but it didnt work. I have the same chromedriver as selenium version, 79.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.9.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.15.1"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

```
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50795/devtools/browser/eff31772-420d-4e78-b3d6-7a13abce8b77
[1578868360.724][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
```

Comment: Have you tried using the updated chrome driver which is of ver. 80 and also upgrade your chrome browser to also .ver 80 and try may be this issue is  of a particular version. download from here http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: 80 is not available yet?

Comment: Please see the link that I have pasted, version 80 is there i cant paste a screenshot over here otherwise i would have pasted.